# Rails Access Association attributes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an html table that renders a partial as follows

```
<tbody id="horse_logs">
  <%= render @horse_logs %>
</tbody>
```

This calls _horse_log.html.erb and iterates through each element in `@horse_logs`

```
<tr id="<%= dom_id(horse_log) %>">
  <td><%= horse_log.id %></td>
  <td><%= horse_log.name %></td>
  <td><%= horse_log.boarder.first_name%></td> <!-- This is the association I want to access -->
  <td><%= horse_log.arrival_date %></td>
  <td><%= horse_log.monthly_boarding_fee %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="link blue large id card icon"></i>'.html_safe, horse_log_path(horse_log)%></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="link green large edit icon"></i>'.html_safe, edit_horse_log_path(horse_log), remote: true %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="link red large remove icon"></i>'.html_safe, horse_log_path(horse_log), method: :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true %></td>
</tr>
```

The issue is that accessing the boarder association inside the partial gives the following error

```
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

So basically the way rails implements this, they seem to be stripping the association data.  The association is set up in my models correctly, and I can access the data in all other ways EXCEPT inside the partial.

How can I force rails to include the entire association.

here is my controller method if this helps

```
def index
  @horse_logs = HorseLog.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order("created_at DESC")
  @horse_log = HorseLog.new
end
```

Comment: This means that there is `HorseLog` record(s) that is (are) not associated with a `boarder` record. You either need to handle this in your code (ex: `horse_log.boarder.try(:first_name) || 'No boarder associated!'`) or make sure that a `boarder` exists for a given `horse_log` (basic presence validation)

Comment: To find all the HorseLog records which are not associated with an existing `boarder` record, you can do `HorseLog.includes(:boarder).where(boarders: { id: nil })`

Comment: @MrYoshiji All fields are populated and every horse_log record has an associated boarder.  The association works except in this partial.  I can `puts @horse_log.boarder.first_name` anywhere else in my code and it works.  Only inside the partial is the boarder stripped.

Comment: Can you confirm that `HorseLog.includes(:boarder).where(boarders: { id: nil })` returns an empty AR::Relation?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I'm an idiot.  You were right.  I had some old records in the table before I implemented validation for that model.

Comment: You're only human, like every developer, it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this but I would try.

```
<tbody id="horse_logs">
  <% @horse_log.each do |horse_log| %>
    <%= render 'horse_logs', horse_log: horse_log %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

If you get the same error, then you will need to make sure that your association is set up correctly.

Does every `horse_log` have a `boarder`? If not, you will get this error every time you run this code. you will need to check that `hourse_log.boarder` isn't nil.

Comment: No, this is the same thing as OP's. If `render` receives a list of records, it will render the partial `"_#{records.first.class.name.underscore}"` for each element in `records`

Comment: I know, the assumption was that Rails was dropping associations, by doing it like this it would be easy to see that that assumption isn't true. I could have done a better job explaining that.

Comment: a horse_log belongs to a border, a boarder can have many horse_logs.  I'm unsure what you're suggesting in your answer, but `@horse_log` doesn't exist in my controller.  the `@horse_log.new` essentially resets my form.  That's all it does.

Comment: The error ```undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass``` is being called on this line. `<td><%= horse_log.boarder.first_name%></td> <!-- This is the association I want to access -->`. That means that `horse_log.boarder` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, try this. It will prevent the error and return nil gracefully

```
<td><%= horse_log.try(&:boarder).try(&:first_name) %></td>
```